# sonar.exclusion still checking files

Tags: angular, sonarqube

I am trying to add sonarqube in angular 10 app.

```
sonar.host.url=http://localhost:9000
sonar.login=admin
sonar.password=admin
sonar.projectKey=sonar1
sonar.projectName=sonar1
sonar.projectVersion=1.0
sonar.sourceEncoding=UTF-8
sonar.sources=src/app
sonar.exclusions=**/node_modules/**, app-routing.module.ts
sonar.coverage.exclusions=*.module.ts
sonar.tests=src
sonar.test.inclusions=**/*.spec.ts
sonar.typescript.lcov.reportPaths=coverage/sonar1/lcov.info
sonar.testExecutionReportPaths=reports/ut_report.xml
```

I have added for exclusion `app-routing.module.ts`,  but it is still being analyzed. Please help, how can i exclude this file.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you want to ignore that specific file the correct syntax is as follows:

```
sonar.exclusions=**/node_modules/**, **/app-routing.module.ts
```

You can refer to this page regarding the exclusion patterns :

https://docs.sonarqube.org/latest/project-administration/narrowing-the-focus/#NarrowingtheFocus-patterns